# How To make an API in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my first time I use WordPress for create apps. In there I want to make an API but don't know how to make it in WordPress.

This my code in the web site :

```html
function drivers_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'driver', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'driver', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'driver', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'      => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'            => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'driver', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'driver', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title','thumbnail' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'rewrite'             => array('slug' => 'driver'),
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'drivers', $args );
}
// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'drivers_post_type', 0 );

// Little function to return a custom field value
function driverMB_get_custom_field( $value ) {
  global $post;

    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $value, true );
    if ( !empty( $custom_field ) )
      return is_array( $custom_field ) ? stripslashes_deep( $custom_field ) : stripslashes( wp_kses_decode_entities( $custom_field ) );

    return false;
}

// Register the Metabox
function driverMB_add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'driverMB-meta-box', 
        __( 'driver Info', 'textdomain' ), 
        'driverMB_meta_box_output', 
        'drivers', 
        'normal', 
        'default' 
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'driverMB_add_custom_meta_box' );

// Output the Metabox
function driverMB_meta_box_output( $post ) {
  // create a nonce field
  wp_nonce_field( 'my_driverMB_meta_box_nonce', 'driverMB_meta_box_nonce' ); ?>

    <p>
        <label><b>ID</b></label>
        <label><?php echo get_the_ID() ?></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo driverMB_get_custom_field( 'username' ); ?>" style="width:100%;" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo driverMB_get_custom_field( 'password' ); ?>" style="width:100%;" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo driverMB_get_custom_field( 'email' ); ?>" style="width:100%;" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label><b>Phone Number</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ext : 088216192560" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo driverMB_get_custom_field( 'phone' ); ?>" style="width:100%;" />
    </p>
    
  <?php
}

// Save the Metabox values
function driverMB_meta_box_save( $post_id ) {
  // Stop the script when doing autosave
  if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

  // Verify the nonce. If insn't there, stop the script
  if( !isset( $_POST['driverMB_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['driverMB_meta_box_nonce'], 'my_driverMB_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

  // Stop the script if the user does not have edit permissions
  if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // Save the textfield
  if( isset( $_POST['username'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'username', esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ) );
  if( isset( $_POST['password'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'password', esc_attr( $_POST['password'] ) );
  if( isset( $_POST['email'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'email', esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ) );
  if( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'phone', esc_attr( $_POST['phone'] ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'driverMB_meta_box_save' );
```

I don't know how to create it as API. My friend told me to create if URL equals then perform action function, but I don't know how?

Does someone tell me or help me to create an API for WordPress?

Answer (score 9):

No doubt there are many other plugins in the market too but these are the two which I used personally for creating APIs in WordPress:

1. Using [WP Rest API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) (Now a days it is officially supported by WordPress):
   The detailed documentation for the same is provided [here](http://v2.wp-api.org/).
2. Using [Json API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin (for simplicity). If you use this plugin then it will allow you to create your "Controller", "Model" etc files and hence you can write your custom endpoints. You can check more details [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/).

Note : I have used this plugin last year and it works great.

Comment: This plugin hasn’t been tested with the latest 3 major releases of WordPress. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I must say:

You must first create a folder in the mainstream WordPress path and place your project files in it.

[image]

Then add your original file with extension .php Put it in it.
Note that you need to move your code based on the function.